# Tradingview Charting - Remove logo

Tags: angular, charts, tradingview-api

I'm using tradingview [charting library](https://github.com/tradingview/charting-library-examples) and I want to remove marketing logo and link rendering over the chart. I think it should be linked with the subscription so, I've to integrate client_id and user_id? Also, where I can get this from my [tradingview](https://in.tradingview.com/) account?

Answer (score 3):

Charting library have different versions, with different code for logotype. Tell your version of charting library, or find in file charting_library\static\bundles\library.******.js Need to delete a little code.

Comment: Hello, I'm interested in this, could you please share for the last version of charting an example how to remove that?

Comment: i cannot share, because charting library does not open source. You can download at official github, or manually from oficial demo page (need download many files by links from browser console with 404 errors. Only one html file need to do download with online html source code website). At latest version 1.15 disable logo is easy.  disabled_features: ["widget_logo",],

Answer (score 3):

You can use this setting in the TradingView (Version 23) widgetOptions:

```
disabled_features: ['widget_logo'],
```