# Displaying TradingView Logo in Advanced Chart Library

Tags: angular, charts, tradingview-api

I have been utilizing the white-labeled version of the Advanced Chart Library in my application so far. However, I am currently in the process of downgrading our license and would like to display the TradingView logo (Chart by TradingView) on the chart.

[image: TradingView logo on Advanced Chart Demo]

Despite the efforts, I was unable to locate a configuration option for re-enabling the TradingView logo in the chart within the documentation.

Could someone kindly assist by providing a solution or guidance on how I can achieve this logo display in the charts with the updated license?

I was looking for a config to add in the *enabled_features* in the Advanced charting library Featuresets but couldn't find any

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tradingview Charting - Remove logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56396454/tradingview-charting-remove-logo)

Comment: @NarenMurali the `widget_logo` option seems to be deprecated from the Featuresets in the latest versions. Couldn't display the logo with this